# how to print to file in bash and display it as "cat" would show

Tags: bash, sed

So when I open a log-file, it’s all one long line. Notepad word wraps it, but it really is one line. When I open a Linux terminal, and I type "cat log-file" it formats the file and does line breaking. Is there a way to take this log-file and output it into a new file how cat displays it?

Sorry if I'm being vague, I'm new to bash, and I'm still trying to learn things.

Could you use the "sed" command to add a \n somewhere in there to break the line?

I am trying to display this file in an html file. so I wanted to replace any \n with an 
 tag. so I'm doing `sed's/\n/<br>/' <log-file >html-file` but its not working. how would i go about that?

Comment: Sounds like you need a better text editor than Notepad. Notepad is notorious for mishandling Unix `\n` linebreaks, and prefers windows style `\r\n` instead.  Don't reformat the file, try a better editor -- upgrade your toolchain!

Comment: For starters, try out [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: May I recommend Sublime Text?

Comment: If you are trying to open in windows then you could try VIM editor for windows here http://www.vim.org/download.php

Comment: You guys are completely right. I tried notepad++ and it works perfect. but then here is my next question. i am trying to display this file in an html file. so i wanted to replace any \n with an <br> tag. so im doing sed's/\n/<br>/' <log-file >html-file  but its not working. how would i go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace all `\n` instances with `<br>`:

```
awk -v ORS='<br>' 1 <log-file >html-file
```

- `awk` reads the input line by line (thanks to the default input record separator, `RS`, being `\n`.
- `ORS='<br>'` sets the *output* record separator, `ORS`, to `<br>`
- `1` is merely a shorthand for `{print}`, which simply prints each input line terminated  with `ORS`.

---

As for why your command doesn't work:

- `sed's/\n/<br>/'` is missing a space between `sed` and its program, `'s/...'`, which results in a *single* string that is not a valid command name.
- Even if you correct that, the command will still not work as intended, because `sed` reads line by line, and each line is read *without* the terminating `\n`; therefore, as written, you cannot replace `\n` in the input, and a `\n` will again be appended on output - effectively, your command would be a no-op.

---

**Update**: @ gniourf_gniourf points out that there is a **straightforward `sed` solution**, too, if it's OK that **instead of *replacing* the `\n` instances, `<br>` is *inserted before*  them** - which should be fine, since the output is *HTML*:

```
sed 's/$/<br>/' <log-file >html-file
```

- `$` matches the *end* of each input line (without capturing anything) and "replaces" it with `<br>`, i.e., effectively appends `<br>` to the line before outputting it `\n`-terminated.

Should there still be a need to get rid of the `\n` instances, you could simply pipe to `tr`:

```
sed 's/$/<br>/' <log-file | tr -d $'\n' >html-file
```

Comment: Well, sorry to contradict you, but there's a straightforward and efficient way using `sed`: `sed 's/$/<br>/'`. Cheers `;)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Good point, thanks - technically that _inserts before_ instead of _replacing_ `\n`, but given that the output is HTML, that should be fine. I've incorporated your command into the answer.

Comment: Ah you're technically right it doesn't replace the newline! but that's what I had in mind anyways since it's HTML... you know... `:D`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf `:)`